# created trigger to send out an email on delete from a table in toad/oracle. is there a way i can capture which user deleted the record?

Tags: oracle, database-trigger, toad

created trigger to send out an email on delete from a table in toad/oracle. is there a way i can capture which user deleted the record?
There are no entries in the table which gives the user id or name to know who deleted the record.

Comment: Assuming that the "user" we're talking about is the database user and not, say, an application user that is logged in via an application and connecting to the database as a shared account, just call the `user` function in the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using:

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') FROM dual;
```

Also, you can use `USER` to frtch the username as following:

```
V_USER := USER;
```

now, you can use the `V_USER` at any where in trigger.
Cheers!!

Comment: V_user := user;  will this get the db user or the user deleting the record from the front end ?

Comment: Username of the user which is logged into the oracle.

Comment: i'm trying to get the user name of the user deleting the record from front end. i realized that this data is being logged into a audit table. Can i use a join in trigger ? Thanks for your advice

Comment: Depends on your requirement, you must have the rights to select from audit table

Comment: I have the rights just want to know how to do a join in trigger to get data from multiple table when a record is inserted.

Comment: Are you talking about oracle unified auditing or do you have any auditing feature in your own application? I think oracle audit tables do not store any user data.

Comment: No we have a audit table we created table_audit which makes an entry when a record is deleted from table.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture any DELETE statement on desired table:

```
audit delete on your_schema.your_table;
```

In order to enable AUDIT you must have auditing enabled. Check your audit settings with:

```
 select * from v$parameter where name like '%trail%';
```

The result should be DB,EXTENDED.  If it's not, you can achieve that by:

`alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;`  -- for this change to take affect, you must restart your DB instance.

Afterwards you will find captured DELETE operations in SYS.AUD$ table in a column SQL_TEXT.